# How to view the change log?

Tags: release-loki

I'm a beginner linux user and as my first linux os I chose elementary and I think its great. But everyday since I installed it(couple of days ago) I get an update for 'Operating System Updates'. Even though it is good to see the distro getting better and better, I can't find a way to see the change log. Is there any way to see it or its not implemented yet?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a changelog to view really. Elementary has been posting frequent Development Updates on their blogs detailing the more major recent changes. You can find those at http://blog.elementary.io